# Optimizing query and join in PostGIS View

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, postgresql-performance

I am developing a webmapping application in which I used PosgreSQL with PostGIS plugin as my DB.

I have this two tables namely; `evidensapp_polystructures` and `evidensapp_seniangcbr`. Both tables contain geometry(multipolygons).

```
CREATE TABLE evidensapp_seniangcbr (
  id serial NOT NULL,
  hazard character varying(16) NOT NULL,
  geom geometry(MultiPolygon,32651),
  CONSTRAINT evidensapp_seniangcbr_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE INDEX evidensapp_seniangcbr_geom_id
  ON evidensapp_seniangcbr
  USING gist (geom);

CREATE TABLE evidensapp_polystructures (
  id serial NOT NULL,
  bldg_name character varying(100) NOT NULL,
  bldg_type character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  brgy_locat character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  municipali character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  province character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  geom geometry(MultiPolygon,32651),
  CONSTRAINT evidensapp_polystructures_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE INDEX evidensapp_polystructures_geom_id
  ON evidensapp_polystructures
  USING gist (geom);

ALTER TABLE evidensapp_polystructures CLUSTER ON evidensapp_polystructures_geom_id;
```

With my query below it takes almost 15 mins. to get the result of `structures` that intersects in `seniang` where is `hazard='High'`. This same goes with `Medium` and `Low`.

```
-- Executing query:
SELECT count(evidensapp_polystructures.brgy_locat) AS High,
       evidensapp_polystructures.brgy_locat AS Barangay,
       evidensapp_polystructures.municipali AS Municipality
FROM evidensapp_seniangcbr
INNER JOIN evidensapp_polystructures ON ST_Intersects(evidensapp_seniangcbr.geom, evidensapp_polystructures.geom)
WHERE evidensapp_seniangcbr.hazard = 'High'
GROUP BY evidensapp_polystructures.brgy_locat, evidensapp_polystructures.municipali;

Total query runtime: 896688 ms.
23 rows retrieved.
```

It is not acceptable. So, how do I optimize it? I've done spatial indexing and clustering based on this [site](http://revenant.ca/www/postgis/workshop/indexing.html).

I have created a view for each `hazard`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW high_seninang AS 
  SELECT count(evidensapp_polystructures.brgy_locat) AS high,
         evidensapp_polystructures.brgy_locat AS barangay,
         evidensapp_polystructures.municipali AS municipality
  FROM evidensapp_seniangcbr
  JOIN evidensapp_polystructures ON ST_Intersects(evidensapp_seniangcbr.geom, evidensapp_polystructures.geom)
  WHERE evidensapp_seniangcbr.hazard::text = 'High'::text
    AND evidensapp_seniangcbr.geom && evidensapp_polystructures.geom
  GROUP BY evidensapp_polystructures.brgy_locat, evidensapp_polystructures.municipali;
```

Which result to this for high hazard:

[image]

How do I use my view to result:
[image]

`polystructures`:

```
INFO:  analyzing "public.evidensapp_polystructures"
INFO:  "evidensapp_polystructures": scanned 288 of 288 pages, containing 9847 live rows and 0 dead rows; 9847 rows in sample, 9847 estimated total rows
Total query runtime: 122 ms.
```

`seniangcbr`:

```
INFO:  analyzing "public.evidensapp_seniangcbr"
INFO:  "evidensapp_seniangcbr": scanned 1 of 1 pages, containing 6 live rows and 0 dead rows; 6 rows in sample, 6 estimated total rows
Total query runtime: 219 ms.
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Comment: Please post an `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` of your query.

Comment: I used the maintenance option in pgAdmin.